# foreach x ( cat file ) in perl?

Tags: perl, unix, cat

Trying to run the code:

```
foreach x ( `cat file`)
echo $x
end
```

Expected output when ran on unix:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

When ran on perl script:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Please advise on how to achieve output like in unix in perl?

Comment: Is your `foreach...` code is running ? Is it `perl` or `shell-script` ?

Comment: That syntax isn't Perl. I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not even in Perl

```
foreach x ( `cat file`)
echo $x
end
```

1. There's no echo or end command in Perl.
2. Why are you using system's cat command? You should use pure Perl for such trivial tasks.

I assume you are trying to loop over contents of a file and then print each line.

In Perl you can do it using below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#always use the below 2 lines in your Perl program
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = '/path/to/file';
#open file in read mode
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Could not open file $!";
#use while to iterate over each line
while my $line (<$fh>){
    print $line;
}
```

Or you could take file's content in an array then loop over it

```
my @lines = <$fh>;
foreach my $line (@lines){
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code :

- I think you want to print element on new line. You just need to attach new line character with the element.

```
@array = (1..10);
foreach my $x (@array)
{
    print "$x\n";
}
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>perl a.pl
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```